# OS X save location permission

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, location, cllocationmanager

I'm getting the users GPS Location like this:

```
var manager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    //manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    //manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:    [AnyObject]) { // Updated to current array syntax [AnyObject] rather than  AnyObject[]
    println("locations = \(locations)")
}
```

The commented-out functions seem not to exist for os x applications. It still works for me so that's fine.

But every time I run the code it asks for permission to use location.
Is it possible to store the permission somewhere, so it only asks on the first execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/):

> Call the `authorizationStatus` class method to get the current authorization status for your app.
>
> If the authorization status is `kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted` or `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`, your app is not permitted to use location services and you should abort your attempt to use them.

Your code on OS X should look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .Restricted || status == .Denied {
        // User permission not given
        return
    }
    
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Permission is managed centrally by Mac OS X. The first time you call `startUpdatingLocation`, it will ask for permission then remembers what the user has decided.

Comment: The _return_ kicks me out of the _viewDidLoad_ function right?
If I want to do other stuff in this function, should I just leave the _if_ empty and put all the manager functions inside an _else_?

Comment: Yes, put the location calls into the `else` block